# Show recently viewed node in a block

Tags: 7, views, blocks, nodes

I want to show recently viewed node in block, this can achieved using [Statistics](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/statistics) module or [recently_read](https://www.drupal.org/project/recently_read) module. But I have disabled statistics module for some reason and recently_read module disables page caching as they mentioned in the project site. Is their any other way for creating the recently viewed block?

Comment: create a cookie which cotains the last viewed node id, then pass cookie value to your view

Comment: @NoSssweat Could you provide a little code and a little more detail in an answer? That sounds like a good solution!

Comment: @NoSssweat Please provide some reference for that

Comment: Check this [link](http://jan.tomka.name/blog/list-recently-viewed-nodes-drupal)

Comment: how many recent nodes you want to show?

Comment: @NoSssweat I want to show 5 recent nodes

Comment: @AmrendraKumar it is working but when I view the same the node the node is not in the top of list

Comment: @AmrendraKumar to me that approach is over kill, also anonymous users can't flag.